# mkinitcpio did not include modules.devname in cpio image

Tags: arch-linux, init, mkinitcpio

I'm running Arch Linux with a customized kernel. I modified the PKGBUILD from abs, and renamed the package to `linux-custom`.

The PKGBUILD is fine, after installation I could see the `modules.devname` in the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/` folder

But that file is not included while creating the initrd image. Perhaps there's something wrong with my mkinitcpio profile?

```
%> cat /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux-custom.preset 
# mkinitcpio preset file for the 'linux-custom' package

ALL_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
ALL_kver="/boot/vmlinuz-linux-custom"

PRESETS=('default' 'fallback')

#default_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
default_image="/boot/initramfs-linux-custom.img"
#default_options=""

#fallback_config="/etc/mkinitcpio.conf"
fallback_image="/boot/initramfs-linux-custom-fallback.img"
fallback_options="-S autodetect"
```

Comment: The preset looks fine; what does the PKGBUILD look like?

Comment: @jasonwryan Hmm, the PKGBUILD is fine I think. The modules.devname is generated and installed to the right place. Do you still think the PKGBUILD matters?

Comment: The preset looks OK, so I wanted to see what was happening prior to generating the initrd.